# Specify profile from gradle task when building app

Tags: quarkus

I use profiles to define the type of my data source at compile time. So, for example, I can build my app with a MySQL configuration by running the command:

```
./gradlew build -Dquarkus.profile=mysql
```

Now I need to create a gradle task for that, but I can't find a way to define the system property only when that task is executed (and not globally when tasks are compiled). Any suggestion?

Marco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody stumbles on the same problem. It is possible to define the profile property when the task graph is ready:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
  taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(project(':my-module').myTask)) {
       System.setProperty('quarkus.profile', 'myProfile')
    }
}
```

This way you can associate a specific task with the profile you want to enable.

If you want to run multiple tasks with different profiles this won't work though, since the context is shared between all tasks. For that I used a GradleBuild task that sets the system property and runs on a separated context:

```
task myTask(type: GradleBuild) {
   buildFile = "build.gradle"
   dir = new File(project.buildDir, "myTask")
   tasks = ['build']
   Map<String, String> systemArgs = new HashMap<>();
   systemArgs.putAll(startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs)
   systemArgs.put("quarkus.profile", "myProfile")
   startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs = systemArgs
}
```